# Websites to whitelist for Micrososft Updates

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, websense

Everytime I try to update my server it ask for username and password. SO im trying to whitelist these links from Microsoft:

https://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb693717.aspx

But im having an issues as I need to provide full URL as websence does not support *. wildcard

ANy help regarding this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Domain Name Sets in Websense supports wildcards. You need to add a domain name set based exception. From Getting Started Guide, [Configuring exceptions](https://www.websense.com/content/support/library/web/hosted/getting_started/isa_exceptions.aspx):

> 1. Under Firewall Policy, select Network Objects from the Toolbox.
> 2. Right-click Domain Name Sets and click New Domain Name Set.
> 3. Give the new set a name (e.g., Forcepoint Web Security Cloud Unproxied).
>
> In the Domain names included in this set section, add all Forcepoint
>   Web Security Cloud global exceptions (from the Forcepoint Web Security
>   Cloud PAC file). These include the following Microsoft Windows update
>   sites:
>
> ```
> download.microsoft.com
> ntservicepack.microsoft.com
> cdm.microsoft.com
> wustat.windows.com
> windowsupdate.microsoft.com
> *.windowsupdate.microsoft.com
> update.microsoft.com
> *.update.microsoft.com
> *.windowsupdate.com
> ```